# Extracting Data From Remote XML & Creating Wordpress Post

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, curl, xml-rpc

I've been searching for some time to figure out how to extract data from a remote XML file and then create a post automatically with the parsed XML data. I have figured out the functions to create a post using cURL/PHP but I'm not sure how to pull data from an XML file, put that data into strings and then apply those strings to a newly created post. Also dupe protection would be nice.

If anybody knows a good starting point for me to learn or has written something ealready that could provide useful assistance then  that would be great. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

PHP has [a wide variety of XML parsing functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).  The most popular around here is the [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).  You can use DOM functions to find the specific XML tags you're interested in and retrieve their data.

Unfortunately you did not provide an example of the XML you're trying to work with, otherwise I'd post a brief example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stay with xml format using php you use something with this [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). If you can change the format to basic csv text you could try using wordpress plugin [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/).

Also php has a function for csv files called `fgetcsv` , so I would say get the information needed from your file.

Pass to a variable and than use `wp_insert_post` to create a post. Put it all in a while or foreach loop and should work fine - Or try the plug-in first.

As for duplicate content, perhaps you could pass the information in an array and then use array_unique to delete any duplicates (just off the top of my head theres probably a better way or function out there).